# Injective differential of linear operators on a Hilbertspace

Tags: matrices, oa.operator-algebras, smooth-manifolds, hilbert-spaces

Given a complex Hilbertspace $\mathcal{H}$ of dimension $\dim(\mathcal{H}) = d$ and the set $$\mathcal{F} := \{q\in L(\mathcal{H})\vert\quad \text{rank}(q) = 4 \quad \wedge \lambda^q_{1,2} < 0\ \ \wedge\ \ \lambda^q_{3,4}> 0 \}$$

of all linear operators of rank 4 and exact two positive $\lambda_{3,4}$ and two negative $\lambda_{1,2}$ eigenvalues. The real dimension of $\mathcal{F}$ is $8d-16$.

Now we look at the spinor-space $S_q$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^4$ and the linear operators $L(\mathcal{H},S_q)$. For some $A \in L(\mathcal{H},S_q)$ with $\text{rank}(A)=4$, $A^*A\in\mathcal{F}$ and an open subset $B_\epsilon(A)$ for $\epsilon > 0$ we define the map

$$R : B_\epsilon(A) \to \mathcal{F},$$
$$B \mapsto -B^*B$$

This map should be well-definied if $\epsilon$ is small enough such that  $\forall C\in B_\epsilon(A): \ \text{rank}(C)=4$.

If we now look at the differential at the point $A$

$$DR_A: L(\mathcal{H},S_q) \to T_A\mathcal{F}$$.

Is this differential injectiv?